# Can I teach PHPUnit that Mage::throwException *always* throws an exception?

Tags: php, magento, phpunit, code-coverage

Magento has a static method that does some extra reporting just before throwing an exception.

```
/**
 * Throw Exception
 *
 * @param string $message
 * @param string $messageStorage
 * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
 */
public static function throwException($message, $messageStorage = null)
{
    if ($messageStorage && ($storage = self::getSingleton($messageStorage))) {
        $storage->addError($message);
    }
    throw new Mage_Core_Exception($message);
}
```

It's *guaranteed* to throw an exception, so it's mildly annoying that PHPUnit's code coverage considers the closing brace after a `Mage::throwException` statement to be uncovered code.

[image: Shows code coverage analysis of code with no coverage following throwException statement.]

I looked through [the PHPUnit documentation](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html), but I don't see any non-hacky way to have it consider the line covered. (I consider putting a dead-code `return` statement at the end of the method hacky, or really anything that we would have to do every time we use `Mage::throwException`.)

Is there some way I can teach PHPUnit that `Mage::throwException` *always* throws an exception, so treat it the same (with respect to coverage) as it would `throw new WhateverException()`?

Comment: Unless [this](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions) helps, I think you're stuck with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also this problem.

Just do:

```
throw Mage::getException(...);
```

and in getException you return the exception object. Otherwise you're stuck with it.